# Loading image to canvas using querySelector

Tags: file-upload, jquery-selectors, html5-canvas, 2d

In the code below $('#initialModel') is a button which opens up a file loader and $('#initialModelImage') is my canvas and am trying to load the image dynamically on to the canvas from the file uploader ,but am not able to see the uploaded image on the canvas.Could someone help me correct my code.Thanks.

```
$('#initialModel').on('change',function(e){
var modelFile=document.querySelector('#initialModel').files[0];
var reader=new FileReader();
if (modelFile)
    reader.readAsDataURL(modelFile); 
else
    $('#initialModelImage').src = ""; 
reader.onloadend = function (_file)
{
    var canv=document.getElementById("initialModelImage");
    var ctx = canv.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(reader.result,640,480);
}
});
```

Comment: I even tried this code  - This code goes inside reader.onloadend =func(){                                                                                                             `code`var canv=document.getElementById("initialModelImage");
var ctx = canv.getContext('2d');
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function() {
  imageObj.src=reader.result;
  ctx.drawImage(imageObj,640,480);
};`code`

Comment: you are passing a string to the source argument of `drawImage()`. This argument has to be either an `<img>` element, a `<canvas>` element, a `<video>` element or an `ImageBitmap` Object in supporting browsers. There are a lot of questions here in stackoverflow which deal with what you are trying to do. Basically, you need to create an `<img>` element, set its `src` to the returned dataURL, and in its `onload` event handler, to call the drawImage method. Your question is unlikely to add any value to these questions, also you may want to delete it.

Comment: Kaiido finally could search the solution